# Is medicine a humanity?What does the humanity here refer to?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, vocabulary

> Yet humanity’s dramatic progress against specific infectious diseases has far outstripped the pace of investment in good health-care systems, responsive governance, dependable infrastructure, and the other more reliable guarantors of health.

This is from an article in *[The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2020/02/coronavirus-spreading-because-humans-are-healthier/606448/)*, whose main point is that despite the great medical advances we are bad at handling public health crisis in many senses. Medicine is a science, not a humanity like literature or philosophy. So I think it should be "science’s dramatic progress". I’m very confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "**Humanity’s** dramatic progress [...] Medicine is a science, not a **humanity** like literature or philosophy.

The first "humanity" is a synonym of "mankind"; "the human race" - In this sense, the noun is uncountable.

The second "humanity" in your example refers what the OED describes as

> b. In plural (usually with the). The branch of learning concerned with human culture; the academic subjects collectively comprising this branch of learning, as history, literature, ancient and modern languages, law, philosophy, art, and music. **Hence also in singular**: any one of these subjects.The humanities are typically distinguished from the social sciences in having a significant historical element, in the use of interpretation of texts and artefacts rather than experimental and quantitative methods, [...].

[My emphasis]

NB: "medicine" = the area of study of medicine